# dimension of a coordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that its zero set in $\mathbb{C}^2$ has cardinality $n$. Is it true that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ is an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space (and why)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the zero set of $I = (x, y^k)$ has cardinality $1$, it's just the point $(0, 0)$.  But $\mathbb C[x, y]/(x, y^k)$ has dimension $k$.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a positive result (see Fulton, *Algebraic curves*, Corollary I.7.4 on page 23). Let $k$ be some algebraically closed field. If $I \subseteq k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ is an ideal, then $V(I) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n(k)$ is finite if and only if $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/I$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space. In this case, we have $|V(I)| \leq \dim_k(k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/I)$.

A more precise result is that that $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/\sqrt{I} \cong \prod_{P \in V(I)} k$, in particular $\dim_k(k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/\sqrt{I})=|V(I)|$.

Comment: This more precise result is the obvious generalization of my post (proven in the same way), correct?

Comment: Correct. Alternatively one can use the classification of artinian rings.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no, but your very interesting question leads to about the most  elementary motivation for the introduction of scheme theory in elementary algebraic geometry.

You see, if the common zero set $X_{\mathrm{classical}}=V_{\mathrm{classical}}(I)$ consists  set-theoretically (I would even say *physically*) in $n$ points, then $N:=\dim_\mathbb C \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I\geq n$.
If $N\gt n$, this is an indication that some interesting geometry is present: $X_{\mathrm{classical}}$ is described by equations that are not transversal enough, so that morally they describe a variety bigger than the naked physical set.
 The most elementary example is given by $I=\langle y,y-x^2\rangle$: we have $V_{\mathrm{classical}}(I)=\{(0,0)\}=\{O\}$
Everybody feels that it is a bad idea do describe the origin as $V(I)$, i.e. as the  intersection of a parabola and one of its tangents: a better description would be to describe it by the ideal $J=\langle x,y\rangle,$ in other words as the intersection of two *transversal* lines.
However the ideal $I$ describes an interesting  structure, richer than a naked point,  and this structure is called a *scheme*.
This is all reflected in the strict inequality $$\dim_\mathbb C \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I=2=N\gt \dim_\mathbb C \mathbb{C}[x,y]/J=1=n=\text { number of physical points}.$$ Scheme theory in its most elementary incarnation disambiguates  these two cases by adding the relevant algebra in the algebro-geometric structure, now defined as pairs consisting of a physical set plus an algebra: $$V_{\mathrm{scheme}}(J)=(\{O\},\mathbb{C}[x,y]/J )\subsetneq  V_{\mathrm{scheme}}(I)= (\{O\},\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I ).$$

**Bibliography**
Perrin's [*Algebraic Geometry*](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Algebraic_Geometry.html?id=Vn1yR9qPvlMC&redir_esc=y) is the most elementary introduction to this down-to-earth vision of schemes (cf. beginning of Chapter VI).

Comment: This is also what I thought when I read Jim's counterexample. There the origin is "thickened $k$-times in the $y$-direction".

Comment: @Martin: yes, exactly.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: That's how I came up with it :)  Helps that I think about infinitesimal schemes for a living.

Answer (score 5):

As Jim points out, this is false in general. The correct statement is that $\mathbb C[x,y]/\sqrt{I}$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space.

**Proof:** Write $\sqrt{I} = P_1\cap \cdots \cap P_m$, where $P_i$ are the primes minimal over $I$. Since $V(P_i)\subseteq V(I)$, we see that each $V(P_i)$ is a single point. Thus since each $V(P_i)$ is distinct, we get $m=n$. Furthermore, each $P_i$ is maximal, so the $P_i$ are comaximal hence by the Chinese Remainder Theorem we get
$$\frac{\mathbb C[x,y]}{P_1\cap\cdots\cap P_n}\cong\frac{\mathbb C[x,y]}{P_1}\times\cdots\times\frac{\mathbb C[x,y]}{P_n}\cong \mathbb C\times \cdots \times \mathbb C$$
with $n$ copies of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: +1 That's a great opportunity to improve my understanding of the link between commutative algebra and algebraic geometry. Could you please explain the following: what is the connection between $V(P_i)$ and the zero set of $\sqrt{I}$?

Comment: @Manos Since $\sqrt{I}\subseteq P_i$ we get $V(P_i)\subseteq V(\sqrt{I})$. Recall also that $V(I)=V(\sqrt{I})$. I hope that answers your question. Note: keep in mind I've implicitly used the Nullstellensatz here in concluding each $P_i$ is maximal.

Comment: @Manos Here I'm using it to denote the variety of $I$. $V(P_i)$ is a single point b/c if $V(P_i)$ were disconnected (say by $A,B$) then we would have $I(A)I(B)\subseteq I(V(P_i))=\sqrt{P_i}=P_i$, thus by primality either $I(A)\subseteq P_i$ or $I(B)\subseteq P_i$ so $V(P_i)\subseteq A$ or $B$, a contradiction. I guess the nullstellensatz is also implicitly used here, in the line $I(V(P_i))=\sqrt{P_i}$.

Comment: Ok thanks, let me work it out.