# What is the dimension of ${\mathbb R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, vector-spaces

I would like to show that ${\mathbb R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ is infinite dimensional as a vector space over ${\mathbb R}$. If I were working over $\mathbb C$ this would follow from the fact that there are infinitely many points in the variety $V=\{(a,b)\in {\mathbb C}^2: a^2+b^2=0\}$. But over $\mathbb R$, there is only one point in $\{(a,b)\in {\mathbb R}^2: a^2+b^2=0\}$. More generally, for a given polynomial $f\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, where $k$ is a field,  I would like to understand how to find the dimension of the quotient of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f)$ as a vector space over $k$, for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: $1,x,x^2,x^3,...$ are linearly independent.

Comment: In general you can choose a monomial order. In your case, for example $y>x$. Then compute the initial monomials of the elements of $(f)$. Note that these are all the monomials $x^my^n$ with $n\geq2$. In the $(m,n)$-plane see which points are not selected as exponents of these monomials. That tells you the dimension. In your case, for this monomial order you get the monomials $x^n$ and $x^ny$ for $n=0,1,2,...$ as a basis.

Comment: You might also like: [real radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_radical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that $\mathbf R[x,y] /(x^2 + y^2)$ is infinite dimensional directly by looking at powers of $x$, and you can explicitly find a basis as suggested in the comments.

As you noticed in your question, in order for you to safely say that the size of an algebraic set coincides with the dimension of its coordinate ring, you should work over an algebraically closed field. But you can [extend scalars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules#Extension_of_scalars) to get the correct reading.

For example, you can extend scalars to find out that $$\dim_\mathbf{R} \frac{\mathbf R[x,y]}{(x^2 + y^2)} = \dim_\mathbf{C} \frac{\mathbf C[x,y]}{(x^2 + y^2)}$$ is infinite because $\{(a,b) \in \mathbf C^2 : a^2 + b^2 = 0\}$ is infinite.

Extension of scalars allows you to assume that $k$ is algebraically closed in your last question. Are you able to answer it in that case?

By the way, it would be more interesting for you to consider the dimension of $k[x_1, \dots , x_n]/I$ for a more general ideal $I$ of $k[x_1, ..., x_n]$. If you are going to relate it to the size of the corresponding algebraic set (over an algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ of $k$), you just have to be careful when $I$ is not radical or $k$ is not perfect. [This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343993/dimension-of-a-coordinate-ring) might be helpful.

Comment: So is this line of reasoning correct: suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a field $k$. Then $V$ is really just (meaning isomorphic to as a vector space over $k$)  $k^n$ for some $n$, that is then the dimension of $V$ over $k$. So if $L$ is a field extension of $k$, and we  regard $V$ as $L^n$, the dimension of $V$ as a vector space over $L$ is of course  the same.

Comment: @Math101 you have to be careful. $V$ is a vector space over $k$, and $L^n$ can be regarded as a vector space either over $k$ or over $L$. As a vector space over $k$, it cannot be identified with $V$ unless $L = k$ (just compare dimensions to see why this must be the case). As a vector space over $L$, it cannot be identified with $V$ since $V$ is a vector space *over $k$*. What is true is that $L^n$ is isomorphic to the tensor product $V \otimes_k L$. That’s the idea behind extension of scalars.

Comment: I will need to study the background on tensor products behind the extension of scalars to understand it. But for now I would like to know how a dimension argument shows that $L^n$ cannot be identified with $V$. What can we say in general about the dimension of $L^n$ as a vector space over $k$? The only obvious thing I can see is that it must be $\leq n$.

Comment: @Math101 if $[L:k] = m$, then $\dim_k L^n = mn$ whereas $\dim_k V = n$. So $V$ and $L^n$ are isomorphic as vector spaces over $k$ iff $m = 1$ (i.e. $L = k$).

Comment: I think I understand what I was getting wrong. Going back to my original question, would you be able to give me a simple argument to show that $$\mbox{dim}_{\mathbb R}\frac{{\mathbb R}[x,y]}{(f)}=\mbox{dim}_{\mathbb C}\frac{{\mathbb C}[x,y]}{(f)}$$ without resorting to the general theory on extension of scalars? 
As for the dimension of $k[x_1,\ldots.x_n]/(f)$ in general, is it true that it must be infinite as soon as $n\geq 2$?

Comment: @Math101 sure. Pick your favorite basis $\mathcal B$ of $\mathbf R[x,y]/(f)$ (as a vector space over $\mathbf R$). By looking at real and imaginary parts, it is straightforward to check that $\mathcal B$ is also a basis of $\mathbf C[x,y]/(f)$ (as a vector space over $\mathbf C$).

Comment: @Math101 and about your last question... yes, it is infinite dimensional unless $f$ is a constant polynomial but I’m assuming you don’t want that :p

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with your idea of "infinitely many points in the variety $V$" you may notice that there are infinitely many **pairs** of points in $V$ of the form $(P,\bar P)$ i.e. such that they are interchanged by complex conjugation, e.g. $P=(1,i)$ and $\bar P=(1,-i)$.

Each of these pair is defined over $\Bbb R$, for instance the pair given above is the intersection of $V$ with $x=1$.

In fact $V$ is an example of *degenerate conic*, i.e. a conic that is not irreducible and splits as a pair of lines. Sometimes the lines are themselves real (e.g. $xy=0$ or even coincidental like $x^2=0$), sometimes are complex conjugate of each other and they meet at a real point.

---

Let me explain how to use the infinitely many *pairs* defined over $\Bbb R$ on $V$ to deduce that $A=\Bbb R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ has infinite dimension over $\Bbb R$. For recall that $A$ is naturally the $\Bbb R$-algebra of algebraic functions on $V$.

Consider an infinite sequence $\{{\cal P}_j=(P_j,\bar P_j)\}_{j=1,2,3,...}$ of such pairs and let
$$
A_k=\{\text{$f\in A$ such that $f({\cal P}_i)=0$ for $i=1,2,...,k$}\}
$$
for all $k>0$. Then $A_k$ is a linear subspace of $A$ and we have
$$
A\supset A_1\supset A_2\supset\cdots\supset A_k\supset\cdots
$$
where each inclusion is proper.

(For instance, if ${\cal P}_j=V\cap\{x-j=0\}$ then
$$
(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k)\in A_k\setminus A_{k-1}.
$$
The situation here is indeed quite simple because $V$ is a conic)

But a vector space containing an infinite filtration od proper linear subspaces must have infinite dimension.

Comment: Is there a way to deduce from this that the dimension of ${\mathbb R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ is infinite?

Comment: @Math101: I thought you had an argument in mind when you said that the dimension over $\Bbb R$ was infinite because you had infinitely many points ...

Comment: Yes, but it still seems to me that the variety $V$ over $\mathbb R$ has only one point, $(0,0)$. How does the fact that over $\mathbb C$ it has infinitely many points help?

Comment: @Math101: You use the fact that there are infinitely many **pairs** of points cut by functions defined over the reals. I edited my answer to give some detail

Comment: Sorry from my slowness, I am understanding some of it but not all. My main question is the relevance of the complex variety $V$ to your construction. Wouldn't the same work for any infinite sequence of distinct real numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots$, by defining $P_i=(a_i,0)$ and then $A_k$ as before? We can then look at $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots (x-a_k)$ that is in $A_k$ but not in $A_{k+1}$. I am also unsure about what it means for the pair $(P_j,\overline{P}_j)$ to be defined over ${\mathbb R}$, since the second coordinate of the points is not in ${\mathbb R}$. I am sure I am missing something basic.

Comment: @Math101: Mind that your $P_i\notin V$. In down-to-earth terms what I mean with the pair $(P_j,\bar P_j)$ defined over $\Bbb R$ is that, **as a pair** is fixed by complex conjugation (acting naturally on points coordinates). Also, note that the pair $(P_j,\bar P_j)$ can be obtained intersecting the real varieties $V$ and $x-j=0$. The situation is very similar to the high school observation that a quadraic real equation may have two compex solutions, conjugated to each other.

Comment: Ok I understand that, but would my construction with arbitrary real numbers $a_i$ work just to prove that $A={\mathbb R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ has infinite dimension, regardless of any algebraic geometry reference to varieties? I can surely consider $(x-a_i)$ as elements of the real vector space  $A$